# git rebase resolve conflicts again and again?

Tags: git

every time i git rebase my patchset on a new version of the original, do i have to manually resolve the conflicts again and again?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem here.  Once you've rebased and resolved the conflicts, surely you are actually changing your commit to a commit premised on the new version of the original.  The next time, you shouldn't have to re-resolve this because you're now applying the updated patch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the same conflict reappear when I use git rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401754/why-does-the-same-conflict-reappear-when-i-use-git-rebase)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out [`git-rerere`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rerere).

Comment: Just to save people from reading all the documentation, you can pretty much just set `rerere.enabled` to true in your .gitconfig, and it'll take care of it all for you.

Comment: In addition to the man pages, the Git maintainer Junio Hamano has a nice blog post about using rerere at http://gitster.livejournal.com/41795.html .

Comment: if youre merging(pulling), just set rerere.enabled, if rebasing, it seems you have to git rerere before and after editing the conflicting file, manually

Comment: And for those searching for how to set rerere.enabled to true in .gitconfig, just execute the command: git config --global rerere.enabled true

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your repository you might be able to use the stash

```
git stash pop
git stash
```

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/10/stashing-your-changes.html