# Multiple features developed in parallel and git merging at once

Tags: git, git-merge

Having such a situation in git graph:

```
dev *
     \_ featureA 
      \_ featureB
```

and I requested merges for each of the features to the `dev` branch.
Both features are developed in parallel and are going to be merged in the same time.

The merge request of the branch `featureA` has been accepted and now when my colleague wants to merge `featureB` he sees merge conflict because in `CMakeLists.txt` in the root directory both of the features add a line in the file at the same place; in `featureA`:

```
CMakelists.txt:10:
    add_subdirectory(featureA)
```

in `featureB`:

```
CMakelists.txt:10:
    add_subdirectory(featureB)
```

The question is should he resolve this merge conflicts by hand or should I rebase the branch `featureB` locally and then repush the branch or maybe there is something wrong in the workflow and other approach should be taken when having such a situation?

Comment: Both solutions are correct. I'd use merge for such situation.

Comment: Rebasing won't necessarily result in fewer conflicts.  There could be fewer or greater conflicts.  For a conflict as small as this, what is wrong with resolving it by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me preface by saying that there is no right or wrong solution here — the way you handle a merge conflict like this depends on what kind of branch `featureB` is.

#### Option 1: rebase if `featureB` is a private branch

If `featureB` is a *private* branch – meaning you're the only one committing to it – then I'd suggest you rebase it on top of `dev` after `featureA` has been merged.

That means going from this:

```
A--B---M dev
 \    /
  C--D featureA
   \
    E--F featureB
```

To this:

```
A--B---M dev
 \    / \
  C--D   E--F featureB
```

Keep in mind that [rebasing is still a kind of merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402549/26396), the difference being that `git-rebase` applies *one commit at a time* on top of the previous one, while `git-merge` merges two commits with their entire set of changes in a single operation.

Doing a rebase forces you to solve the conflict *at* the commit that introduced the conflicting change. This has a couple of advantages:

1. It gives you more context around the change, thus making it easier to find a resolution.
2. The resolution will become part of the commit itself – where it belongs – instead of ending up in a merge commit, potentially mixed up with other unrelated conflict resolutions.

#### Option 2: merge if `featureB` is a public branch

If, however, `featureB` is a *public* branch – that is, multiple people commit to it, then you can't rebase it because that would be [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). In that case, you're better off handling the merge conflict in a regular merge on the `dev` branch.

The resulting history will then look something like this:

```
A--B---M------N dev
 \    / \    /
  C--D   E--F featureB
```

where `N` is where you resolve the conflict.