# Why doesn't git modify patch after resolving a rebase or cherry-pick conflict?

Tags: git

Something I never quite understood is why, when I rebase on, say, `master` and resolve conflicts, and then `master` is updated and I go to rebase again on `master`, I have to re-resolve all the conflicts I had previously. I know `rerere` exists to help with this, but I'm confused on why that has to exist on the first place. I have a question similar to the comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3516899/3813411) original post:

> Once you've rebased and resolved the conflicts, surely you are actually changing your commit to a commit premised on the new version of the original. The next time, you shouldn't have to re-resolve this because you're now applying the updated patch?

Shouldn't `git`, once I resolve the conflicts at a given pick stage in the rebase, modify the patch so that it's compatible with the new base commit? In other words, I rebase onto `master`, resolve all those conflicts. Then `master` is updated with a new commit. Say they change a completely unrelated file I didn't touch. I rebase onto that. What's going on step-by-step with git that's causing me to need to re-resolve the conflicts that I had from last time? As I said I would think since rebasing creates new commits that those updated patches would be modified to not conflict with the new base.

Comment: It would help if you provided an example: create a repo on GitHub, for instance, in which rebasing, then rebasing again, shows these conflicts. Others can then clone the repo and experiment with the same rebase commands. The reason this would be helpful is that in most cases, re-rebasing *doesn't* force you to re-resolve conflicts.

Comment: If rebasing once, then rebasing again, is *not* what you mean, then again, an actual example would be helpful. This is what the term [mcve] is all about...

Comment: @torek thank you - I realized I'm not able to reproduce the same behavior I was seeing before in a new repo, so I'm assuming there's probably something I was doing wrong that was causing it to happen each rebase. I'll update the question with a MRE if I am able to reproduce it.